# Debug issue in eclipse while getting DB connection

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have problem in debugging java program while getting connection but program executes successfully and get desired output.

below is my code to get connection object.

```
public class CRMConnection
{
private static String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:1521:dbname";
private static String username = "crmuser";
private static String password = "crmuser";
public static Connection getConnection()
{
Connection conn=null;
try
{
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println("exception1:"+e)
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
{
    System.out.println("exception2:"+e)
}
return conn;
}
```

Below i m calling the getConnection() method from another class.

```
Connection conn = CRMConnection.getConnection();
```

if i run the program in eclipse with normal mode, i m not getting any issue. i'm getting desired output.
But if i run the program in debug mode, i m getting below method call stack while executing CRMConnection.getConnection() but program executes successfully if i keep on press F8.

I dont know exactly why eclipse is displaying below call stack while executing getConnection() . Is it problem with my code or eclipse debug issue?

i m getting in eclipse debug window in method call stack.

```
FileInputStream.open(String) line: not available [native method]
OracleDriver.<clinit>() line: 313
Class<T>.forName0(String,boolean,ClassLoader) line: not available
CRMConnection.getConnection() line : 19
```

Need java expert advise.

Comment: That's not a stack trace. A stack trace starts with an exception and its message. Stop ignoring exceptions using empty catch blocks. Replace them with `throw new RuntimeException(e);` if you don't want to handle checked exceptions. That will get you a real stack trace.

Comment: i tried to print the exception inside catch block but it didnt get printed in console. i m getting DB connection and program executes successfully in normal and debug mode. The above error it did not stop my program execution but while debugging i m getting.

Comment: To print a stack trace, you need `e.printStackTrace()`. Not `System.out.println("exception1:"+e)`. And yes, it will be printed in the console, unless the console is redirected to some file.

Comment: Yes JB Nizat. you are correct. we need to use e.printStackTrace().you mean to say there is problem with my code? if its a problem with my code, how come i m getting connection object and fired sql query.

Comment: I don't mean anything. You're asking about the cause of an exception you're getting, but don't provide the stack trace. So it's basically impossible to answer. WHat I can tell is that your exception handling is terrible. You're ignoring exceptions, and that is never a good idea.

Comment: yes i will handle the exception. i m in the process of writing exception class. I wont leave this exception as it is.I will handle it. its not a stack trace. its method call stack. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So, there is no problem at all. You're just seeing which method your driver calls internally to open a connection.